# <br style="margin-bottom:8px;"/> not rendering in IE

Tags: html, line, break

I'm trying to create a space and a half between the text and the date in my website without using two "< br/ >" tags. The code that you see below works perfectly fine in Firefox but it doesn't work at all in IE. If I use two "< br/ >" tags, it creates too much space and I only want one space and a half without using CSS. I know that I can easily do this with CSS but the code that I have works fine in FF and it just doesn't work in IE. I think for some reason IE doesn't like "margin-bottom" and it's not rendering it all.

Code:

```
<p class="text">blah blah blah<br style="margin-bottom:8px;"/>17 August 2013, 2:30pm EST</p>
```

Output in FF:

```
Blah blah blah blah

17 August 2013, 2:30pm EST
```

Output in IE:

```
Blah blah blah blah
17 August 2013, 2:30pm EST
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use two p tags and control the margin on them or use line-height to give you what you want. I can't comment specifically without seeing more of the code.

But something to try whilst waiting for another answer.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I can use that for now.